# My data is randomly sent, using java http connection

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I wrote a minimal method to post some binary data over HTTP but the data is not actually sent every time.
I saw many other questions that looks like this one, but none solved my problem.
Here is my java method

```java
    public static int http_post ( String server , byte [] data )
        {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null ;
        try {
            URL url = new URL( server ) ;
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection() ;
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST") ;
            urlConnection.setDoOutput( true ) ;
            urlConnection.getOutputStream().write( data ) ;
            return urlConnection.getResponseCode() ;
            }
        catch ( Exception e )
            {
            return -1 ;            
            }
        finally 
            {
            urlConnection.disconnect() ;
            }
        }
```

On the client side, it works well: the returned code is always 200. (that's why I don't treat the exception in this simple code).

But when I look at the server side, I see that the data is some time well received, and some time not.
It's completely random : when I re-run, what is received or not is different.
When the data is not received, the received request contains a correct "Content-Length" but the body is simply not there (nor the double *EOL*).
I got the same behavior on several servers : my own one (that hosts my web pages), a very small and local one I wrote in python and *https://httpbin.org/anything*.

I tried many variant (with *flush*+*close* on the output stream, playing with timeouts, *useCache* or not, calling *connect()* before to send, with a *sleep* before *getResponseCode*...)
I can't figure out what is wrong in my code, especially since it's random.

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection(), it looks like you have to call the .connect() function before sending any data. You may also want to call .disconnect() at the end.

Comment: You should also log the error instead of just catching it. I believe that would be e.printStackTrace().

Comment: The code you've posted is missing `flush` and `close`, but you mention you tried those.  I assume you tried them BEFORE calling `getResponseCode` as this is important.  The only other thing that could be happening is an exception, as @SupaMaggie70b advised, so logging any exception in this code would be helpful.